# Can I use WinSCP in read-only mode

Tags: ftp, winscp

I use WinSCP to view a file system over FTP.

Most of the time, I only wish to view files on the file system - but I do occasionally need to modify or delete files.

Is there a setting in WinSCP (or any other common Windows FTP clients) that can let me choose whether to access an FTP file system with read-only or read-write permissions.

This will allow me to avoid any accidental changes to the FTP file system.

If I'm asking the question in the wrong way, apologies - I guess the most general phrasing is "how can I view an FTP file system without write permissions?"  But I am pretty tied to WinSCP, so the ideal is a solution involving that.

Comment: I'm not sure about read-only access, but if you're worried about accidental drag-and-drop (which I used to have a lot of trouble with), there's a setting in WinSCP that'll require confirmation of any drag-and-drop action. I regret that I no longer remember where to find it, and on this Linux box I'm unable to install WinSCP and find it, but it definitely exists, if that helps to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WinSCP does not have setting like that.

In general, the best solution is to log in with account that has read access only.

Comment: how can I create an account that has read access only in WinSCP or any other ftp client?

Comment: @ElsdenIep You cannot create account in WinSCP or any other FTP client. You create account on the server. If you need more details, please ask a separate question (and post a link here).

Comment: Thanks Martin. Thanks for the explanation. I have posted a new question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1509191/create-ftp-account-with-read-only-access-in-directadmin. It would be highly appreciated if you could have a look.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Create .ftpaccess file in directory that needs to be read-only for account username@yourdomain.com.

Content of the .ftpaccess file:

```
<Limit WRITE>
DenyUser username@yourdomain.com
</Limit>
```

That's all.

Please note:

- Commands in .ftpaccess file are recursive (i.e. affects all the files
  in the current directory and any subdirectory).
- Condition is that server supports ProFTPD.

More about ProFPTD  here:

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html

Warning: ProFTPD is quite powerful. If you make a mistake and therefor you can't edit your files via FTP anymore, you can still edit .ftpaccess file via the command line.