# Create FTP/SSH account with read-only access in DirectAdmin

Tags: ssh, ftp, user-accounts, hosting

I have a developer who wants to check website files on the server. In the past, this developer has made changes that broke the website.
In order to avoid unwanted file editing, I need to grant the developer access in some sort of read-only role.
The hosting is on DirectAdmin.

Question is: How can I create a FTP/SSH user with read-only (and perhaps download) credentials?

Help and suggestions to achieve this are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Create .ftpaccess file in directory that needs to be read-only for account username@yourdomain.com.

Content of the .ftpaccess file:

```
<Limit WRITE>
DenyUser username@yourdomain.com
</Limit>
```

That's all.

Please note:

- Commands in .ftpaccess file are recursive (i.e. affects all the files
  in the current directory and any subdirectory).
- Condition is that server supports ProFTPD.

More about ProFPTD  here:

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html

Warning: ProFTPD is quite powerful. If you make a mistake and therefor you can't edit your files via FTP anymore, you can still edit .ftpaccess file via the command line.